# Copy every nth element from one array to another.

Tags: processing

Does anyone know of a way to copy every nth element from one array to another? For example, I have a file containing a dataset of numbers related to a collection of images, where each number in the dataset  represents things such as an average user rating(e.g.6.4), the file name, (e.g. 221324) and so on.

However I only want to copy the average rating numbers out into another array. The first average rating is found at element 3 of the array and then every 11th element on from that is another average rating  number for the next image.

This is in the Processing language by the way and while Processing does have an array called subset() which allows you to copy an array of elements from an existing array to another array, like this:

```
String[] averageMaxes=subset(numbers, 3, 1);
```

I can't figure out how to start at the 3rd element in the array and then copy every 11th item. In the above line of code, the subset function takes as parameters the name of the array it's copying from, the starting position and the number of elements to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a basic for loop.

```
for(int i = 3; i < averageMaxes.length; i+=11){
   //copy index i over to target array
}
```